# QTableView horizontalHeader makes it very laggy?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qtableview

I have the code below, and I noticed that when I hit ctrl+A to select all rows it feels laggy, taking about 1 second to complete the selection. However, I also noticed that if I hide the horizontal header with `self.horizontalHeader().hide()`, the lag completely goes away! Why does this happen? And how can I get rid of the lag but keep my header?

```
from PyQt5 import QtGui, QtCore, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import sys

class SeriesModel(QtCore.QAbstractTableModel):
    def __init__(self, series):
        super().__init__()
        self.series = series

    def columnCount(self, parent=None):
        return 1

    def rowCount(self, parent=None):
        return len(self.series)

    def data(self, index, role=None):
        row = index.row()
        col = index.column()
        if role == QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole or role == QtCore.Qt.ToolTipRole:
            return str(self.series[row])

    # The headers of this table will show the level names of the MultiIndex
    def headerData(self, section, orientation, role=None):
        if role in [QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole, QtCore.Qt.ToolTipRole]:
            if orientation == Qt.Horizontal:
                return str(self.series.name)

class SeriesView(QtWidgets.QTableView):
    def __init__(self, series):
        super().__init__()

        self.setModel(SeriesModel(series))

        # self.horizontalHeader().hide()

# Examples
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)

    series = pd.Series(np.random.randn(1000000)).rename('MyData')

    view = SeriesView(series)
    view.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the highlightSections property is enabled by default in the QTableView header. This property means that if an item is selected, the item in the header that implies a repaint is also selected, in your case you have 1000000 so it will be repainted a similar amount of times. So a possible solution is to disable that property:

```py
class SeriesView(QtWidgets.QTableView):
    def __init__(self, series):
        super().__init__()
        self.setModel(SeriesModel(series))
        self.horizontalHeader().setHighlightSections(False)
```